# GIMP script-fu, can "file-glob" return only files with particular extentions?

Tags: python-2.7, scripting, glob, gimp

I'm trying to use python-fu in GIMP. I would like pdb.file_glob to return an array of image files in the format I specify. I tried:

```
myGlob = "*.png|*.PNG|*.jpg|*.JPG|*.gif|*.GIF|*.xcf|*.XCF"
globpath = os.path.join(patternDir, myGlob)
num_files, files = pdb.file_glob(globpath, 0)
```

But the files array is always empty, I assume because the glob syntax is invalid.

Note that if I use `myGlob="*"`, I get the graphics files I want, but I also get files such as "fake.txt", which I want to exclude.

Comment: And any online documentation for this function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The doc of all PDB functions can be found via the Python-fu console. Hit the `Browse...` button and then enter your search in the filter bar at the top of the left pane. This documentation is dynamic, it includes the documentation of any callable plugin/script (as long as authors have written some of course)

The PDB functions for Python are a direct mapping of the script-fu API. In this specific case `file_glob()` was very recently added to the script-fu API because there is nothing in the base TinyScheme language to do it. In Python, you are better off using the standard Python API, `os.walk()` or `glob.glob()/glob.iglob()`.

In any case such functions only do simple pattern matching, if you want several extensions you want something like this:

```
sorted([filename for ext in ['XCF','xcf','jpg','JPG','jpeg','gif','GIF'] for filename in glob.glob('*.'+ext)])
```

Edit: this is a "comprehension", more or less a loop with the inner instruction outside. You can read it as:

```
files=[]
for ext in ['XCF','xcf','jpg','JPG','jpeg','gif','GIF']:
    for filename in glob.glob('*.'+ext):
        list.append(filename)
```

Comment: Thanks xenoid! I'm unfamiliar with this syntax. What is the effect of the "filename" on the left side of the left-side loop?

Comment: I made an exts array, and changed your line to `sorted([filename for ext in exts for filename in glob.glob(patternDir + '\*.' + ext) ])` and tested it in the console, it works like I want. But I don't understand it well enough to do  it again myself :)

Comment: Yes, array is a good idea. General syntax is a Python "comprehension", see edited answer.